# "You are connecting to Redis v3.2.9, Sidekiq requires Redis v4.0.0 or greater?"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis, sidekiq

I recently updated Sidekiq in my Gemfile:

```
gem 'sidekiq', '~> 6.0', '>= 6.0.4'
gem 'redis', '~> 4.1', '>= 4.1.3'
```

But ever since updating, I get this error when running `sidekiq` in Terminal:

```
You are connecting to Redis v3.2.9, Sidekiq requires Redis v4.0.0 or greater.
```

I made sure to uninstall old versions of both Sidekiq and Redis, but Sidekiq is still trying to connect to 3.2.9. My Gemfile.lock has:

```
sidekiq (6.0.4)
  connection_pool (>= 2.2.2)
  rack (>= 2.0.0)
  rack-protection (>= 2.0.0)
  redis (>= 4.1.0)
```

Am I misreading this error? How would I tell Sidekiq to use the correct version of Redis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was not a gem dependency issue. I ran `brew upgrade redis`, restarted `redis-server`, and that fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

For me the problem was that `bundle exec foreman s` used Redis version specified [here](https://github.com/guilleiguaran/fakeredis/blob/master/lib/redis/connection/memory.rb#L17). Monkey patching with `6.2.5` helped, but the correct way to fix it is to pin your redis version in app_config.yml:

```
redis:
    <<: *redis
    version: 4.2.0 # or the version you are using
```